Узнать текущий битрейт видео
Возможно узнать текущий битрейт видео, живой.
Проигрывается видео, как узнать битрейт в данный момент?
Через javascript
Использую библиотеку
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/MediaPlayerEvents.html#event:PLAYBACK_RATE_CHANGED

попробуйте .getQualityFor('video')
